# JavaScript: JXON conversion, is there a reason for the "@"?

Tags: javascript, json

I have an XML like this:

```
<calendar>
    <month year="2013" num="5">
        <day num="1">
    </month>
</calendar>
```

that I convert to JSON via MDNs JXON Snippet 3. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JXON#Algorithm_.233.3A_a_synthetic_technique

The result is:

```
{"calendar":{
    "month":[{
        "@year":2013,"@num":5,"day":{
            "@num":1
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

This happens because the JXON Snippet 3 does this:

```
vResult["@" + oAttrib.name.toLowerCase()] = parseText(oAttrib.value.trim());
```

Is there some reason to use a "@" here? To me it doesnt make sense since I cant do

```
calendar.month.@year
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a reason, and that reason is indirectly from XPath (A standard when it comes to navigating an XML document programmatically). Attributes are commonly referred to as `@attribute` to distinguish them from content or children tags, to be able to have a two-way operation (if you did not have them, going back from JSON to XML would be impossible due to the ambiguity).

In programming terms, prefer doing `calendar.month["@year"]` over `calendar.month.@year`. It will also have the indirect benefit of making optimizers understand that the name is literal.